# Получить доступ к методу класса activity из другого класса/интерфейса

Tags: java, android, activity

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать передачу размера экрана устройства из MainActivity андроид проекта, в другой класс этого же проекта

```
static Display phisDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
public static Display getPhisDisplay() {
    return phisDisplay;
}
```

Т.к. getWindowManager() не является статическим, как и DisplayMetrics такой вариант не проходит. Как сделать через создание объекта MainActivity внутри класса, который эти параметры принимает, не представляю.
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавать ссылку на Activity в другие объекты не очень хорошая идея, так как и хранить static переменные в Activity. Есть несколько вариантов

1. Можно создать класс Singleton и при запуске активити в методе onCreate() установить в него значения, затем в любом месте можно получать данные.
2. Создать свой класс, при создании активити получить размер и в объект установить только значения (размер экрана).

Comment: а почему "Передавать ссылку на Activity в другие объекты не очень хорошая идея, так как и хранить static переменные в Activity"? А то я как раз так и сделала. Если я создам класс Constants, и потом буду получать в активити нужные мне значения Constants.DISPLAY_WIDTH, так будет лучше?

Comment: Когда передаешь ссылку на Активити или Context Активити в другой объект и в нужный момент она не очистится - будет утечка памяти, static переменные имеется ввиду какие-то объекты, константы static типа int, string  и т.д. хранить в принципе можно.